# C++ how to delete two pointers of classes referencing each other

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a problem with c++ pointers

I'm a C# and VB.NET programmer, but I have converted to C++ recently, so I'm a C++ new newbie somehow

Now I'm writing a subtitle editor and I have two classes a subtitle Paragraph class containing a list of pointers to all of its lines

And a subtitle line class containing a pointer to its parent paragraph (to invoke a method in parent when line has changes )

In the subtitle paragraph class, when I delete the list of pointer to the sub lines they don't get deleted

I tested this by trying to use the pointers after deleting them and call some functions and they work!

I also used "System Monitor" in Ubuntu to tell how much memory does my application use before and after allocating space for the pointers
and I found that it gets increased after allocating memory but the space doesn't get freed after I delete the pointers

So I have a couple of questions:
    
1- can I have two classes each of which referencing to each other?
    
2- when I replace a pointer in one of the two classes with a reference does the same problem still exists
    
3- if I have two classes each of which referencing to each other how can I break this reference manually

I know I can use a shared pointer or weak pointer classes but I want to do it manually first

Here is a sample of my two classes to demonstrate the problem in my application

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class B;

class A
{
    public :
      void setB(B *b){_b = b;cout << "set B" << endl;}
      ~A();
    private:
    B *_b;

};
class B
{
    public :
        void setA(A *a){_a = a;cout << "set A" << endl;}
        ~B(){cout <<"B is dieing" << endl;/*delete _a;*/}
    private:
        A *_a;

};

A::~A(){cout << "A is dieing" << endl;delete _b;}

int main()
{
    getchar(); // two have some time to know how much memory does my application use before allocaing space for pointers

    A *a = new A;
    B *b = new B;

    a->setB(b);
    b->setA(a);

    getchar();// two have some time to know how much memory does my application use after deallocaing the space

    delete a;
    delete b;

    // but here,after deleting it, it's still there, not deleted! I can use it
    a->setB(b);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance

Yasser Sobhy

Comment: Try to redesign what you've made, so they don't refer to one another.

Comment: Can you show us what valgrind tells you about your program?

Comment: I can't use Valgrind because I'm using Ubuntu x64 bit and there is some issues with valgrind in x64 bit systems

Comment: @yasseryasser: I don't see why the known limitations of valgrind on 64bit systems would matter for your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having deleted an object, you could make the pointers point to NULL so you would not be able to use both of them anymore.

When you free a memory space in the heap, blocks are considered as free so they will be overwritten on any further memory allocation. But if not, you can still use it as you saw. But it is obviously not a good practice at all.

Comment: But why the freed memory does not go back to the system

Comment: It will in every cases when your process will be terminated, because your OS will mark every memory pages that were allocated for it as free.

Comment: @yasseryasser What happens with process memory requested by runtime code from OS, and then freed by the program, is OS and runtime specific. It might not be "freed" to the OS until program terminates. But it's all virtual memory anyway, so it does not matter much, at worst it will be swapped to disk once and then never read back, just cleared when process terminates. Programs rarely have memory use peak at start only.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question "can I have two classes each of which referencing to each other?",  the answer is obviously yes. But you then need to constantly think about "who owns the memory? When is this pointer valid?  When is it invalid?  How do I know if and when it changes?"

In C#, you never had to care because the reference counting and garbage collector built into the .Net framework took care of memory ownership and management for you, and automatically did the right thing at the right time.  In C++ it's the programmer's responsibility to think about such things.

What works well in C++ is to allocate objects on the stack in the context that owns them.

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a.setB(&b);
    b.setA(&a);

    return(0);
}
```

Now, when main() goes out of scope, both a and b will be destroyed automatically.

This can still run into the real issue you've created for yourself.  Does the A class really need to keep and hold a copy of the pointer to the B?  Often, A only needs the reference to B during the execution of a certain method.  Instead of holding onto the copy, why not pass it in just when it's needed?

```
a.doesSomethingWithB(parm1, parm2, &b);
```

That way A doesn't have a long term commitment with B.

Keeping a copy of anything means the copy can get out of sync with the real thing.  This is the reason we have the "Don't Repeat Yourself" rule (aka D.R.Y., aka the One Definition Rule.)

When I'm reviewing C++ code, I look for instances of the "new" operator, because that tells me the developer is going to manually manage the memory, and this means he or she has to be extra careful with destructors, pointers, copies of pointers, managing lifetime, all this extra stuff that will make the code more complicated.  Complicated code leads to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

just because you delete a or delete b doesn't mean that the pointer is changed to null.

Look at: [Why Doesn't delete reset its pointer to null](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/188538/why-doesnt-delete-reset-its-pointer-to-null#)

think of it as you pass the address stored in a to the delete operator.
delete frees the memory address but doesn't modify the variable holding the address.
A good tactic is

```
delete a;
a = null;
```

referencing objects after deletion is undefined behavior.

Comment: But why the freed memory does not go back to the system

Comment: @yasseryasser What tells you it doesn't??

Comment: @yasseryasser, the recording of memory allocation happens in tables managed by the C library.  When you delete an object, the entry in the table is deleted, but the values stored in the memory are not set to zero.  You still have a pointer referring to that memory after it's been deleted (called a "dangling pointer") which will still find data at those locations.  In the case of your code above, the memory still looks like the old objects that used to occupy the space. In another app that memory could have been reallocated by another "new", and reusing your pointer would lead to a crash.